How can I run/start an async periodic task in the background in FastAPI
Assuming to have a list of Callable async tasks and I wish to run them in a background with a periodic timing. How can I design this with FastAPI?
In my toy example I tried the BackgroundTasks but as far as I understood:

the tasks in list are not run concurrently but in a FIFO order -> to bypass this I tried defining a Callable async function that take the list and run it concurrently with asyncio.gather()
the tasks seem not to be run in the background when I replicate the code in my (more complex) codebase: maybe I am mis-using the library but it seems that the FastAPI server is not able to serve other requests once I start the background task, i.e. I can not access the /docs and other requests fail with a gateway timeout error.

Here my example:
from fastapi import FastAPI, BackgroundTasks
from src.utils.logger_utils import get_logger
import asyncio
from enum import Enum

app = FastAPI()
logger = get_logger(__name__)

class BaseTask:
    def __init__(self, name, wait_duration: int):
        self.name = name
        self.running = False
        self.wait_duration = wait_duration

    async def __call__(self):
        while self.running:
            await self.run_task()
            logger.debug(f"{self.name} completed, waiting for {self.wait_duration} seconds...")
            await asyncio.sleep(self.wait_duration)

    async def run_task(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def start(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False

class TaskB(BaseTask):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

    async def run_task(self):
        logger.debug(f"{self.name} running...")
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

class TaskC(BaseTask):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

    async def run_task(self):
        logger.debug(f"{self.name} running...")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)

period_in_seconds = 10

class TaskList(str, Enum):
    TASK_A = "TASK_A"
    TASK_B = "TASK_B"
    TASK_C = "TASK_C"
    ALL = "ALL"

tasks = [
    TaskB(TaskList.TASK_B.value, period_in_seconds),
    TaskC(TaskList.TASK_C.value, period_in_seconds),
]


@app.post("/start-tasks/{task_names}")
async def start_task(task_names: TaskList, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    task_names = task_names.value
    if task_names == TaskList.ALL.value:
        to_be_started = tasks
    else:
        to_be_started = [t for t in tasks if t.name == task_names]

    task_coroutines = []
    for task in to_be_started:
        task.start()
        task_coroutines.append(task())

    async def callable_run_tasks():
        # Should I await the coroutine here?
        await asyncio.gather(*task_coroutines, return_exceptions=True)

    background_tasks.add_task(callable_run_tasks)
    return {"message": f"{[t.name for t in to_be_started]} started"}


@app.post("/stop-tasks/{task_names}")
async def stop_task(task_names: TaskList, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    task_names = task_names.value
    if task_names == TaskList.ALL.value:
        to_be_stopped = tasks
    else:
        to_be_stopped = [t for t in tasks if t.name == task_names]

    for task in to_be_stopped:
        task.stop()
    return {"message": f"{to_be_stopped} started"}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8085)

EDIT: the question was closed because already answered here, but I believe this is different for the following reasons:

I don't wish to use a thread but an async coroutine.
The async coroutine examples provided refers to startup/lifespan tasks which is a different use case: in my use case I wish to start them after the app and control them with a provided API as in my example. These tasks should be able to call also other APIs on the same server. Think of them as sub-apps/sub-services which are divided in a modular and logical way to separate concerns.
I wish to run them in the background and I found out that FastAPI implements a BackgroundTask object. Since it is provided I believe it serves a purpouse, which is similar to what I ask but seem not suited AS IS to my use-case. I wish to tweak it.
The provided examples to not cover my specific needs, not it is a provided a complete example that integrates those needs together.

EDIT 2:
A parallel GitHub discussion on the Starlette repository was created here where it seems the BackgroundTasks feature is not intended for my use-case.

Have you looked at APScheduler's asyncio support? https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/modules/schedulers/asyncio.html

I wish to use built-in libraries or Starlette/FastAPI frameworks features if possible without external libraries. Moreover, I have a problem integrating my use-case with these concepts, meaning I believe it is possible but I have to code it right. Using another library adds more info to learn and to integrate correctly.
